# TwinCat 3 with 2 PLCs starting in Config mode time to time. what can be the reason?

Tags: plc, twincat

```
I have such an issue running TwinCat3 with 2 PLCs - it starts time to time in CONFIG mode.
The OS is Win7 SP1
TC3 is in version 3.1.4022.16 but we also I've that with the same result on 3.1.4024.35 on 3 different machines.


In logs I have errors as below : 
Port_852
   11/10/2022 10:01:59 AM 816 ms
   PLC: Timeout while checking file Plc\Port_852.autostart.

Init44\IO: Set State TComObj PREOP OP: Check for autostart >> AdsError: 1817 (0x719, ADS ERROR: device has a timeout)

Init44\IO: Set State TComObj PREOP OP: Check for autostart >> AdsError: 1804 (0x70c, ADS ERROR: not found (files, ...)) << failed%!

PLCs size is :

PLC1: Size of generated code: 500392 bytes 
PLC2: Size of generated code: 1428418 bytes
```

Can this be related e.g. to PLS size ? 2nd one that fails to boot is 3rd time bigger.
Also i did the test and added 2 same PLCs with size 500392 bytes, and again 2nd one failed to load.

Did someone had same issue ?
Is the size can be the issue ?
Maybe I can tweak the timeouts somehow ?

Comment: Hi Tomasz, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you fix your [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)? And also explain a bit better what you're doing and what you've tried to fix it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the controllers licensed correctly? Not temporary licenses which have expired? Check the licensing arrangement maybe? this could be affecting the boot into run mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
I have both test and production machine. Test - with trial versions, production - license as HW card - and its properly licensed.
Both behave same way.